# Experiencing timeouts while Querying big data using Entityframework 4.1 or higher

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4.1, repository-pattern, unit-of-work

using EF 4.1, I am trying to query large data table with 50 thousand. I have set comparatively higher timeout for DbContext as:

```
   public class YourContext : DbContext
{
  public YourContext()
    : base("YourConnectionString")
  {
    // Get the ObjectContext related to this DbContext
    var objectContext = (this as IObjectContextAdapter).ObjectContext;

    // Sets the command timeout for all the commands
    objectContext.CommandTimeout = 500;
  }
}
```

but still it seem no enough but while i Take(10000), it works. I don't have option for server side paging here. It would be great to know how to get rid of this situation of timeouts.

Is it caused by implementation or repository pattern or EF cannot handle large data?

Answer (score 1):

You have taken a bad path there...

It is a bad practice for loading all the data from the data base.
It would be better if you implemented server side paging, or if you dont need padding simply implement the on demand loading functionality.

I dought that the user will view all that data, so there is no need of getting it from the database.

It is better to spend some more extra hours/day but to make it right.

And as practice shows you will have complains from the customers/clients/users about the performance and you'll have to rewrite the hole thing properly.

You better think twice and don't be lazy ;)

Comment: +1 "you will have complains from the customers/clients/users about the performance and you'll have to rewrite the hole thing properly"

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I realize serverside paging can solve only problem in my scenario out of those 50 thousand data I have to group them based on category (for example Category A will have 100 rows and need to show sum of amount on that), at end of day the number of unique category is not more than 20 rows. Since I have not designed database i don't have choice to break this flat data table in to relational model.

Answer (score 0):

EF can handle large data.

It is just a configuration, as you already figured out that most "Connections" have (You also use timeOut in ADO.net).
By default it is set to 30 seconds and you have the ability to change it

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to determine the maximum data that EF can handle in the current scenario of yours.I would suggest to opt for lazy loading but it won't solve the problem altogether. If I were at yours place I would had tried to use some caching feature as pagination is also not feasible in yours case.

These are only my suggestion not solutions.